# Can line and light maintenance be combined?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Is there any possibility to combine line maintenance and light maintenance (containing A, B and C check) under the name of line and light maintenance? In real is there any company which possesses a line maintenance which carried out "A" check and so on?

Comment: you should add a country, Im not an ame but in Canada operators can get there own maintenance scheduled approved by Transport Canada. I have know idea any of the details.

Answer (score 0):

Line maintenance is activities that can be carried out in the turn around time between flights should something need replaced or repaired.

Although considerably less intensive than D checks, A, B, and C checks can still take anywhere from 8 to 72 hours depending on which one and how many problems. There would not be enough time to perform an A, B, or C check on the line. Not to mention it would cause a huge problem for airports (imagine what sitting on the line for 8 hours for an A check at an airport like ORD would cause), and would cause quite a logistical problem for airlines moving equipment around.

However I would expect that maintenance activities considered "line maintenance possible" will be taken care of when an A, B, C, or D check is accomplished.